# Use custom metatag generated from reactjs code

Tags: 8, meta-tags

I have a chart layout used in ContentTypeX Manage Display. Using reactjs, this chart is converted into an image using `toDataURL` process. Now I have a Rule that creates a Post content with the URL of ContentTypeX. Whenever a ContentTypeX is created, a post is also created with the URL of that ContentTypeX. My main goal is to get a preview link of this ContentTypeX URL with the image (converted chart), same how facebook works. To do this, I use metatag(opengraph).

**Problem:**

Using the metatag code below in reactjs, this successfully renders/displays the metatag in the header part of html.

```
<MetaTags>
   <meta property="og:image" content="data:image/png;base64,XXXXX" />
</MetaTags>
```

**QUESTION:**
**But how can I use this custom metatag in a proper configuration. I want to have a link preview of an image in the post.**

**Tested:**

I tried to test a regular content type Article configured with metatags and the image successfully displayed in the post. That is declaring the node fields in the content metatag. See attached image.

[image]

Comment: What’s the issue? I use og_image and it shows a path to my image. Is it because you want it in base64 and not the path to the file?

Comment: Thanks for your interest to this issue. The concern is how to be able to use that custom metatag in opengraph configuration to display that image as link preview.